# Why does carbon dioxide forms simple molecular structure, but silicon dioxide forms giant covalent structure?

Tags: covalent-compounds

I was wondering about this in class, drawing the structures of carbon dioxide and silicon dioxide.

Carbon and silicon are both in Group 4/14, but coming up with oxygen, one can only form a simple molecular structure while the other can form a giant covalent structure. I found no satisfactory in my chemistry textbook and online. What difference between carbon and silicon is this caused by?

Answer (score 3):

Silicon is larger than Carbon, so Silicon's electron cloud is more diffused. Thus, if a hypothetical  bond was formed between Silicon and Oxygen, the p - orbitals would not be able to come close enough to overlap enough to form a sufficiently strong  bond. The  bond would be too weak, and not enough energy would be released in this hypothetical bond formation, so this is energetically unfavourable.

Answer (score 1):

Compare it to the analogical case $\ce{N≡N}$ versus tetrahedral $\ce{P4}$ with 3 single bonds per atom.

Carbon forms in $\ce{CO2}$ or $\ce{CS2}$  2 double bonds, while silicon in $\ce{SiO2}$ or $\ce{SiS2}$ 4 single bonds.

Generally, elements from the 2nd period (C, N, O) have a stronger ( C,N much stronger) tendency to form double/triple bonds than their counterparts in the 3rd period ( Si, P, S), mostly because of better overlapping of p orbitals at forming [$\pi$ bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_bond).

If there is bad orbital overlapping, eventual $\pi$ bonds are weak and multiple single bonds are energetically preferred to 1 multiple bond. By other words, forming hypothetical $\ce{O=Si=O}$ would release much less energy than forming polymeric $\ce{(SiO2)x}$

Comment: What about the analogous $\ce{CS2}$ and $\ce{SiS2}$? Is there something special about 2nd period elements making multiple bonds with each other, or is it sufficient to have one 2nd period bonding partner for a tendency to form multiple bonds.

Comment: CS2 is molecular, SiS2 is polymeric, even if differently to SiO2.

Comment: CS2 is also notoriously unstable to combustion.